# Why doesn't my jQuery sortable table work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to follow

http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/

And have created a very simple example

http://jsfiddle.net/6wbZQ/

It's very straightforward and I'm stuck figuring out why my table is not sortable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing:

```
<script>$("#sort tbody").sortable().disableSelection();</script>
```

before the table has been added to the document. Call `sortable` after the DOM [has loaded](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#sort tbody").sortable().disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6wbZQ/1/